# Turn off notifications of Google Maps requests for information

Tags: notifications, google-maps

Google Maps is requesting information of places I've visited. For example: Google Maps - Starbucks - Answer quick questions to help others. How can I turn this notification off? I just want to disable these notifications, not all notifications from Google Maps since I think it provides notifications during navigation as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Open Maps
2. Open the left panel (swipe left -> right)
3. Click on 'Settings'
4. Click on 'Notifications'
5. Click on 'Your contributions'
6. Toggle the 'Questions about places' setting (and/or any others)

The options i have available can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of available options]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

Comment: This is correct.  But I wish there was a way to request this stuff only over wi-fi.  It just pushed a question with a big image out to me over my limited cellular :(  So I entirely disabled User Contributions Notifications which I don't really want to do.

Comment: Wish I could disable this only for certain places I've visited.

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Menu → Settings → Notifications → Your contributions → Disable questions about places*